# Github use a base repo on my project

Tags: git, github, repository

This might be a stupid and dumb question but, it's something that is bothering me and I can't really find the answer for it, there is any way to take a base repo as a start point on another project?

For example, imagine that I create a git repository that is base sass startup project that as all the dependencies needed on the package.json and the gulpfile.js aswell and all the scss files ready too. It's possible to pick that project and "clone it" to my new project that already as a git repo without doing it manually by creating the files or downloading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a clone of an existing repo that is not attached to the original remote, you can:

```
git clone git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
cd <repo>
git remote remove origin
```

At this point you have a clone, with no connected remote repository. You can use something like this to push one branch (in this case `master`) to a new remote:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<user>/<newrepo>.git
git push -u origin master
```

If you need to mirror many branches or tags, using the `--mirror` flag to `git clone` may be faster; see [man git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

---

If you already have a project and would like to add files from another repository, you can add that one as another remote and fetch from it:

```
git remote add other git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
git fetch other
```

After this you can use for instance `git checkout` with a path to pick out specific files or paths from a commit (or branch) the other project:

```
git checkout other/branch -- path/to/file
```